# Calling a method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I'm totally new to Javascript and this seems like something that should be very simple, but I can't see why my code isn't working. Here's an example of the problem I'm having:

```
//Thing constructor
function Thing() {
    function thingAlert() {
        alert("THING ALERT!");
    }
}

//Make a Thing
var myThing = new Thing();

//Call thingAlert method
myThing.thingAlert();
```

An object is created, but I can't call any of its methods. Why, in this example, is thingAlert() not being called?

Comment: The object returned by `Thing` does not have any methods. All you do inside the constructor function is creating a **local** function. That function is garbage-collected after `Things` terminates. It works the same way like with any other function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Thing constructor
function Thing() {
    this.thingAlert = function() {
        alert("THING ALERT!");
    };
};
// you need to explicitly assign the thingAlert property to the class.
//Make a Thing
var myThing = new Thing();

//Call thingAlert method
myThing.thingAlert();
```

Comment: The OP can do so in his own time if he feels this is the best answer, he doesn't need to accept it just because you were the first to solve his problem. Anyway, you could add some more explanation as to *why* it is needed ;)